# Angular Form Wide validation (not field specific)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angularjs-directive

What is the "Angular" recommended way to validate conditions that involve multiple fields on a form?  Most or all of the validation examples that I have seen talk about custom validation directives that attach to a single textbox,select,etc.  What about conditions that involve multiple fields on a form?

For example, I want to have an "empty" form validator: This will prevent submits on forms that have no required fields and all fields are empty.

Another example is, say I have a master/child one-to-many relationship on a page and the child relationship is a table of child records.  What if I need to validate that at least one child record should exist IF 2 or 3 fields meet certain conditions?

One thought that I have is to built validation directives that attach to <form> tags as elements.  Something like `<form name="xxx" validate-not-empty >` This directive will then set the $invalid property of the form, on submit.  But I am concerned that this maybe is not the angular away to go as I have not seen this on any code samples I have seen.  So I am looking for any alternatives to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with having your "not-empty" directive placed on each of your input field? (following this way of doing: http://angularjs.io/how-to-create-a-custom-input-validator-with-angularjs/)

Then you can just check anywhere if the form is valid, for example to disable the send button:

`<button ng-disabled="!form.$valid">Send</button>`

For it to work you must have all input with its ng-model.

I didn't quiet understand your master/child problem. It you could give an example...

Comment: The link in your answer deals with custom validation on a specific field. I need validation based on the values of multiple fields on a form. Also, having a non-empty directive on each field is not what I need. I need to validate if all fields on a form are empty and prevent submission

Answer (score 0):

I've used the basic validation, based on input type (email, tel, etc.) and the "required" attribute. But, more complex validation is typically handled through custom directives. Although, there may very well be a library that I'm not aware of that provides a common set.

As a basic example:

```
<form name="contactForm">
    <input type="text" name="ContactName" ng-model="contact.name" required>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submitForm(contactForm)" />
</form>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
$scope.submitForm = function (form) {
    if (form.$valid) {
        ...
    }
}
```

---

This W3Schools page describes Angular's validation fairly well.

[AngularJS Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp)

Toward the bottom of the article, they mention that custom validation requires a bit more effort. But, they provide examples.

> To create your own validation function is a bit more tricky. You have
>   to add a new directive to your application, and deal with the
>   validation inside a function with certain specified arguments.

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required my-directive>
</form>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.directive('myDirective', function() {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
          function myValidation(value) {
            if (value.indexOf("e") > -1) {
              mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', true);
            } else {
              mCtrl.$setValidity('charE', false);
            }
            return value;
          }
          mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
        }
      };
    });
</script>
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this does not help.  My question is not how to implement custom validation on a field. Rather I need a way to handle custom validation of a condition that depends on multiple fields on the form

Comment: I understand. I was hoping that the link and description on custom validators would point you in the proper direction. The key is to create custom directives. Without knowing what validation you're trying to perform, it's hard to say exactly what you need. But, with custom directives, you have a lot of control at both the form and field level. Can you share an example of what you're trying to validate?